# CSS and Flexbox: Getting a Footer to Stick

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

Tools: CSS and Flexbox

Note: This question is strictly a CSS/Flexbox aesthetics question

Problem: My footer will not stay planted these days.It shrinks and slips off the page as you resize vertically.

I use to have a nice [Holy-Grail layout](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/holy-grail/) and the header and footer stayed in their places as you shrunk the window vertically while the middle  content gave way.

Life was great- until I translated my CSS into React's JSX style, which has **forced me to wrap an extra div around my footer.**

**Before when life was great:**

```
<div class="main-container"> /*flex-direction:column
     <div class="header">
     <div class="canvas">   /*my pretty flex rows*/
     <div class="footer">
```

**After translation ruined my week:**

```
<div class="main-container"> /*flex-direction:column
     <div class="header">
     <div class="extra-container"> /*dang you React*/
        <div class="canvas">   
        <div class="footer">
```

You can check out this puzzle here http://jsfiddle.net/wd6o22dr/

**The Brain Teaser for you Front-End Masters:**

Considering that keeping that "extra-container" is a must, how do you keep the footer from shrinking and slipping off the page as you resize the page vertically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Considering that keeping that "extra-container" is a must, how do you
>   keep the footer from shrinking and slipping off the page as you resize
>   the page vertically?

One option you have is absolute positioning.

**HTML**

No changes.

**CSS**

Add four rules to existing declaration block.

```
#footer {
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute; /* NEW */
    bottom: 0;  /* NEW */
    z-index: 1;  /* NEW */
    width: 100%;  /* NEW */
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/wd6o22dr/1/